# What does ic_launcher stand for?

Tags: android, icons

It seems that `ic_launcher.png` is the canonical name for launcher icons for Android apps.  What does "ic" stand for?  My guess is "icon", but that's kind of a strange way to abbreviate it, so I'm wondering if it's something else?

Comment: [Use common naming conventions for icon assets](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#DesignTips)

Comment: @adneal, could you put this in an answer so I can accept it?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, no problem. All taken care of.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your assumption is right. The "ic" stands for "icon".

Comment: Glad they used "ic" instead of "icon". "icon" would have been way too long. Seriously though, sometimes I don't get why people did what they did.

Answer (score 10):

From Android's [Icon Design Guidelines: Use common naming conventions for icon assets](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design#use-common-naming-conventions-for-icon-assets), "ic" stands for "icon".

Answer (score 0):

"It's a 48×48 pixel png file called ic_launcher.png (ic for icon, launcher for the launcher screen)"